# Mule Devkit show up the Inbound Properties

Tags: mule, devkit

we can put some keys and values by using `callback,Process("Test", Map<key, Object>` in @Source method.

In this way, we only put the properties into the Output-> Inbound Properties. we can show them out.

But I found that the mule built-in connector can show like that : 
[image]

So, Is there way for me to change the display using Devkit? thanks a lot.

Comment: Any chance you could check your question? It is really difficult to work out what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry for poor English, What I ask is that whether I can change the Inbound properties and show them out using Devkit.